# Access to Mongoose.Query fields

Tags: mongoose, hook

I'm working on a Mongoose hook (pre find) that should edit the original query in case of the query itself contains some particular fields.

So basically the code is similar to this one:

```
MySchema.pre('find', function (next) {
    if (this.foo) {
        this.bar = 'something'
    }
}
```

I just can't read this property, `this.foo` is always undefined, even if the test `this instanceof Mongoose.Query` returns true.

Is this instance just write-only or there is a way in which I can read the object passed to `MyModel.find(query)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved like this:

```
MySchema.pre('find', function() {

    const q = this.getQuery();
    if (q.foo) {
        this.where('bar', 'something');
    }
}
```